# Why is the (non-generic) Stack class implemented as a circular buffer? (and what does that mean exactly)?

Tags: .net, stack, circular-buffer

The non-generic [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx) class states "Stack is implemented as a circular buffer."

I don't understand the application of a circular buffer to a Stack use case. I also don't understand *how* stack could be implemented as as circular buffer.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) says this:

> The useful property of a circular buffer is that it does not need to have its elements shuffled around when one is consumed. (If a non-circular buffer were used then it would be necessary to shift all elements when one is consumed.) In other words, the circular buffer is well suited as a FIFO buffer while **a standard, non-circular buffer is well suited as a LIFO buffer**.
>
> Circular buffering makes a good implementation strategy **for a queue** that has fixed maximum size.

So...how is stack implemented as circular buffer, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that is a copy/paste/edit error in the documentation; looking in reflector, it is *not* implemented as a circular buffer; for example push is (after the resize code) basically:

```
this._array[this._size++] = obj;
```

peek is:

```
return this._array[this._size - 1];
```

and pop is:

```
object value = this._array[--this._size];
this._array[this._size] = null;
return value;
```

Note it doesn't use any kind of offset/wrap-around - so it is *not* actually using a circular buffer. Your instinct looks right, but the documentation looks wrong.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I should have just looked in reflector. :-)